# Media Exception in J2ME emulator: Timed out while making a camera snapshot

Tags: java-me

I have tried to run some J2ME codes for camera snapshot application in netbeans 6.7, 7.0 versions but whereas it shows BUILD IS SUCCESSFUL!, the emulator fails to take a snapshot and instead displays a message that Media Exception: Timed out while making a camera snapshot.Please help me on this, and if you want the codes I can show them.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and I could not solve it,although it worked fine in devices.If you like to use captured image after snapping it,you can use an image(that is in your resource),fileconnection API and getResourceAsStream() to write that image in emulator and then